# reloading django admin inline form updating data from the back end

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a ModelForm for a parent model and and an InlineForm for a foreign key related model.  The Inline form data is read only and can only be updated via a file upload.  I have this working on the intial creation and save, but if you replace the students by uploading a new file, while the data updates properly after the upload and save, the inline form doesn't reload properly right after this save and displays an error.  However, if you navigate away and return everything looks good.

Models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, verbose_name = "Room Name ")
    code = models.TextField(blank=False)
    file = models.TextField(blank=False)


    class Meta(object):
        managed = False
        db_table = 'public\".\"room'


class Student(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name="students, to_field="room_id", db_column="room_id")
    student_id = models.TextField(blank=False, primary_key=False)

    @property
    def grade(self):
        return util.get_grade(self.student_id)

    class Meta(object):
        managed = False
        db_table = 'public\".\"student’
```

admin.py

```
class StudentsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Student
    form = StudentInlineForm
    formset = StudentFormSet

    readonly_fields = ('student_id', 'grade')
    extra = 0

    def get_actions(self, request):
        '''
        Removes the delete action
        '''
        actions = super(StudentsInline, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False


class RoomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def student_count(self, obj):
        return obj.students.count()
    student_count.short_description = " Total Enrolled "

    form = RoomForm
    list_display = [name', ‘code']
    readonly_fields = ['student_count']
    list_per_page = 25
    inlines = [StudentsInline]

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(RoomAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        form.instance.file = 'processed file'
        form.instance.save 
        formset.save()
```

forms_admin.py

```
class RoomsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoomsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[‘name'].required = True
        self.fields[‘code'].required = True
        self.fields['file'] = forms.FileField(
            label='Upload your enrollees:'


    def load_file(self, upload_file):
        student_list = []
        data = upload_file.read() #simplified for this example
        for s in reader:
            s_id = s[0]
            new_student = Student(student_id=s_id)
            student_list.append(new_student)
        return student_list

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        room_form = super(RoomsForm, self).save(commit=False)
        enrollee_list = self.load_file(self.instance.file.file)

        if instance.room_id is None:
            instance.file = 'uploaded'
            instance = super(RoomsForm, self).save(commit=True)

        Student.objects.filter(room_id=self.instance.room_id).all().delete()
        instance.students.add(*enrollee_list)
        return instance


    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = '__all__'


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What error does it display?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: It is a generic "Please correct the errors below".  So, on the initial save, it runs thru that grade look up function perfectly.  When you upload a second time on an existing Room object, right after the save it loops thru the grade look up but is missing the student_id.  Also, while the student count in the parent object displays correctly, the "rows" or instances for the Inline tabular form match the prior count.

Comment: It looks like the issue is validation in options.py:    formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(request, new_object, change=not add)

Comment: You have lots of little mistakes in the code you posted here (missing quotes, parens and others), correcting might make it easier for others to help. But it's complex, if no one tackles it you may want to build a more minimal example that behaves like this. You also do some odd things like overriding methods just to call their `super`, it makes it harder to understand the workflow.